Update model value when signal input changes
Goal: I want to reset the activeIndex when the message input changes.
It doesn't seem appropriate to use a computed signal because the value isn't solely calculated from the input.
Possible solutions:

Set allowSignalWrites: true in the effect and write the value.
In the effect, write the signal value in an untracked block.

Both of these seem like they are sub-optimal.
Stackblitz
Code:
interface Message {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly contentA: string;
  readonly contentB: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="setTab(0)" [style.font-weight]="activeIndex() === 0 ? 'bold' : 'normal'">Tab A</button>
    <button (click)="setTab(1)" [style.font-weight]="activeIndex() === 1 ? 'bold' : 'normal'">Tab B</button>

    <div>{{ activeIndex() === 0 ? message().contentA : message().contentB }}</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  readonly message = input.required<Message>();
  // Can't pass equality check for input?
  readonly computedMessage = computed(() => this.message(), {
    equal: (a, b) => a.id === b.id,
  });

  // Assume activeIndex is hooked up to some tab control
  readonly activeIndex = model(0);

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      const message = this.computedMessage();
      // Want to reset activeIndex when a new message is passed
      // this.activeIndex.set(0);
    });
  }

  setTab(index: number) {
    this.activeIndex.set(index);
  }
}

let count = 0;

const getNextMessage = (): Message => {
  ++count;
  return {
    id: count,
    contentA: `MessageA-${count}`,
    contentB: `MessageB-${count}`,
  };
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadNext()">Load next</button>
    <hr />
    <app-child [message]="message()" />
  `,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {
  readonly message = signal<Message>(getNextMessage());

  loadNext() {
    this.message.set(getNextMessage());
  }
}


Using untracked() inside the effect() is much safer than {allowSignalWrites} and Angular is planning to drop the allowWriteSignal option:https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/56501

Convert the input to an observable using toObservable, so that you can listen for changes. Then we trigger the reset logic.
Also the extra compute is not needed instead you can go for distinctUntilKeyChanged
...
export class ChildComponent {
  readonly message = input.required<Message>();
  activeIndex$ = toObservable(this.message).pipe(
    distinctUntilKeyChanged('id'),
    map(() => {
      this.activeIndex.set(0);
      return this.activeIndex();
    })
  );
  // Assume activeIndex is hooked up to some tab control
  readonly activeIndex = model(0);

  constructor() {
    this.activeIndex$.subscribe();
  }

  setTab(index: number) {
    this.activeIndex.set(index);
  }
}
...

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  computed,
  effect,
  input,
  model,
  signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { map, distinctUntilKeyChanged } from 'rxjs';

interface Message {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly contentA: string;
  readonly contentB: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <button (click)="setTab(0)" [style.font-weight]="activeIndex() === 0 ? 'bold' : 'normal'">Tab A</button>
    <button (click)="setTab(1)" [style.font-weight]="activeIndex() === 1 ? 'bold' : 'normal'">Tab B</button>

    <div>{{ activeIndex() === 0 ? message().contentA : message().contentB }}</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  readonly message = input.required<Message>();
  activeIndex$ = toObservable(this.message).pipe(
    distinctUntilKeyChanged('id'),
    map(() => {
      this.activeIndex.set(0);
      return this.activeIndex();
    })
  );
  // Assume activeIndex is hooked up to some tab control
  readonly activeIndex = model(0);

  constructor() {
    this.activeIndex$.subscribe();
  }

  setTab(index: number) {
    this.activeIndex.set(index);
  }
}

let count = 0;

const getNextMessage = (): Message => {
  ++count;
  return {
    id: count,
    contentA: `MessageA-${count}`,
    contentB: `MessageB-${count}`,
  };
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadNext()">Load next</button>
    <hr />
    <app-child [message]="message()" />
  `,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {
  readonly message = signal<Message>(getNextMessage());

  loadNext() {
    this.message.set(getNextMessage());
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(PlaygroundComponent);

Stackblitz Demo

Appreciate the reply. This solution seems somewhat similar, in that it's "going around" how signals should work. By converting it to an observable in this fashion it's essentially just running the setter on short timeout because of how the observable scheduler will run.

Also, looks like they are considering adding an equality check for inputs which will be cool: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54111

@EvanTrimboli Then the suggestion you have mentioned about effect and untracked is the correct approach
